# 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386, linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker

i've read many posts related to this error but still facing with this problem.
i am using [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) in my project, when i declare MMDrawerController in app delegate file like
 `MMDrawerController *drawerController;`

then is works correctly but when i declare it in Constant.h file and import Constant.h file in appDelegate file and try to create build then it give me following error

```
 duplicate symbol _drawerController in:
/Users/icecube/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VenueFinder-eowuotuoweptcnfmzowyaajchlnv/Build/Intermediates/VenueFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VenueFinder.build/Objects-normal/i386/NavigationViewController.o
/Users/icecube/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VenueFinder-eowuotuoweptcnfmzowyaajchlnv/Build/Intermediates/VenueFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VenueFinder.build/Objects-normal/i386/ViewController.o
duplicate symbol _drawerController in:
/Users/icecube/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VenueFinder-eowuotuoweptcnfmzowyaajchlnv/Build/Intermediates/VenueFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VenueFinder.build/Objects-normal/i386/NavigationViewController.o
/Users/icecube/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VenueFinder-eowuotuoweptcnfmzowyaajchlnv/Build/Intermediates/VenueFinder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/VenueFinder.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

don't know what i am doing wrong? i already checked and not imported .m file instead of .h
If 
`MMDrawerController *drawerController;`
this declaration is in appDelegate file then it works fine but if this declaration is in Constant.h file and import Constant.h file in AppDelegate.m file then it gives error.

Comment: Remove projects derived data from xcode and quit the xcode and build again.

Comment: Show the declaration of drawerController.

Comment: MMDrawerController *drawerController; when i move this declaration from appDelegate file to Constant.h file..then build fail this above error

Comment: @Divyesh You mean exactly as described in my answer?

Comment: Yes i already tried that but still not solved. @trojanfoe

Answer (score 0):

Same variable exits in both class like gobally so declare it locally, like

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    MMDrawerController *drawerController;
}
```

it seems you declared this variable in implementation part in both class, I mean in **.m** file.

Like

```
@implementation ViewController
MMDrawerController *drawerController;
```

Answer (score 0):

install MMDrawerController via pod 
**pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.7'**

remove manual import of library in your project.
Xcode is getting duplicate paths for your MMDrawerController, so better check **LINKER search Path** in Build Settings.